# Do we work with delegates or instances of delegates?

Tags: c#, delegates, terminology

Just terminology...from what I understand, delegate is type and one needs to have its instance. Thus I do not assign method to delegate but to instance of that delegate, is that right? Seems that on MSDN they are sloppy or I did not understand it well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's close to right. You have an immutable delegate instance. And you can add methods which have the same signatures as the delegate type to it, which creates new delegate instances. So for example with a delegate type `Func<int>`:

```
Func<int> f;
```

An instance doesn't exist yet.

```
f = () => 5;
```

Now we have an instance of it.

```
f += () => 6;
```

The old instance is gone and now we have a new one. But when you call `f()` both methods will be executed. The return value will be that of the last one added to the delegate instance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes and no. The "delegate" as the term is most often used refers to the "method reference" which you might call the "delegate instance". In the logical sense, this instance is the "delegate"; it refers to the actual method which callers will utilize to perform some task they can't or shouldn't do themselves.

When you define `public delegate void MyDelegate();`, you are defining a "delegate type", which states the proper signature of methods that can be used as delegates in this case. It's the difference between a class and an object; a class is the template, an object is an instance conforming to the template.

Answer (score 0):

The term "delegate" is used to refer to two different things:

1. A static class which defines a method signature and return type, and includes some 'glue' logic.

   An instance of an object with an Invoke method whose function signature matches that of a static class described above.

Unfortunately, I'm unaware of any standard nomenclature to distinguish them, but perhaps one might use the terms "Delegate signature" and either "ActionDelegate" or "FunctionDelegate".

Incidentally, the terms "object", "reference", and "destructor" cause similar confusion.  I prefer to use the phrase "object ID" to refer to the variables which point at "object instances", use the term "reference" exclusively for pass-by-reference parameter semantics, and avoid "destructor" altogether in favor of "finalizer" and "disposer".